# fetch data from server using xamarin with realm

Tags: xamarin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to create mobile app using `Xamarin` and `Realm`. I am trying to pull data from server and load it into objects extended by RealmObjects.

*code to fetch data from server*

```cs
public async void getCompanyMaster() {
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(URL, string.Empty));

    try
    {
        getConnection();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Company company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(content);

            Debug.WriteLine("Company List " );
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error {0}", e.Message);

    }       
}
```

realm model company

```cs
namespace DesignModel.Model.Master
{
    public class Company : RealmObject    
    {
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "companyMaster")]
        IList<CompanyMaster> companyMaster { get; }
    }
}
```

realm model for company master

```cs
namespace DesignModel.Model.Master
{        
    public class CompanyMaster : RealmObject
    {       
        public string companyAddress { get; set; }
        public string companyId { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }

        public string companyPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now the issue is at following line in `getCompanyMaster` function

```cs
Company company = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(content);
```

it raises an exception

> Error Error setting value to 'errorMessage' on
>   'DesignModel.Model.Master.Company'.

if i do not extend my class from `RealmObject` then it works fine but when i add `RealObject` it doesn't work.

the above approach does work in android native but do not know why it doesn't work in xamarin.

*sample json*

```js
{
  "errorMessage": "",
  "status": "Ok",
  "companyMaster": [
    {
      "companyAddress": "123 Coffee Street\nSuite 300\nRedmond, WA 98052\nUSA",
      "companyId": "cec",
      "companyName": "Contoso Entertainment Systems",
      "companyPhoneNumber": "425-555-0156"
    }]    
}
```

complete stack  trace

> [0:] Error Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error setting
>   value to 'errorMessage' on 'DesignModel.Model.Master.Company'. --->
>   System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The PCL build of Realm is being
>   linked which probably means you need to use NuGet or otherwise link a
>   platform-specific Realm.dll to your main application.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your received Json

Comment: i am using it in Xamarin.Forms and version is 1.1.1 only

Comment: stacktrace is added

Comment: You need to add the `Realm` package to each of your native projects just as you added it your PCL (Forms) library project.

Comment: Thanks a ton @SushiHangover , i am fan of realm as i have used in android native hope choose realm for Xamarin also works well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a note from documentation found here

https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/

under [Getting Started - Prerequisites](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#prerequisites)

> **Important note for PCL users** - this works via the [NuGet Bait and Switch
>   Trick](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/). You
>   have to install the Realm NuGet package into every PCL that uses Realm
>   as well as each of your platform-specific projects, e.g.: your final
>   app for iOS and Android. If you are using shared projects, you only
>   have to install the NuGet into each platform-specific project.